# Does verilog have a way to make global parameters in a single file similar to VHDL package storing constants?

Tags: verilog

Does verilog have a way to store global parameters in a single file similar to VHDL package storing constants?

Would it be correct to use systemVerilog for this

```
// File my_pkg.sv

package my_pkg;

    class my_class;
    endclass
    enter code here
endpackage
```

Then this in the main code

```
`include "my_class.sv"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SystemVerilog has a package concept similar to VHDL (no coincidence). And most modern tools that support Verilog also support SystemVerilog.

---

What you would do is

```
package my_pkg;

class my_class;
endclass
`include "other_class_files.svh"
enter code here
endpackage
```

Then in your code

import my_pkg::*;

See http://go.mentor.com/package-import-versus-include

Comment: Hi Dave_59 thanks for the reply. I mostly use VHDL for my FPGAs but due to a xilinx IP I need to use a verilog code block.

I have edited the post can you tell if its the right way to do this or there is a different way?

Thanks